# Integer separate by commas regex

Tags: javascript, regex, integer

I am searching an issue to create a regex which allow one or more integer (with no-comma) separate by a comma.

There is some exemples:

```
1 -- OK
1.48 -- NOT OK (must be only integer, separate by coma)
1,24 -- OK
1,54,36 -- OK (and actually 54,65,78,...,... etc etc)
1,15,2, -- NOT OK (coma at the end, must be an integer)
1, 2, 54, 63 -- NOT OK (space)
```

I have something like this, which is obviously not ok for my case:

```
^\d+(,\d+)$
```

Which validate only: int,int

Thank you for your help !

Comment: i think you just want `/^[\d,]*$/`

Comment: Try `^\d+(,\d+)*$`. See: https://regex101.com/r/FBlOEC/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your examples, what I understand is that you want something like this:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```